# Open all files with a certain extension in Powershell

Tags: powershell, glob

On Linux if I am in a directory and I want to open all .py files with an application (such as atom), I would simply type `atom *.py` and then all .py files will open with atom. If I type the same thing in Powershell, I receive an error, so I assume the syntax is different on Powershell. How would I accomplish this with Powershell?

Sorry if this is a very beginner question, its my first time using Powershell.

Comment: please, add the error message to your Question. most PoSh errors have details that make problem solving _much_ easier than "i had an error". [*grin*]

Comment: On Windows, globbing is done by the command, not by the shell

Answer (score 1):

Collect the files you want to open first, then pipe them to the call of your external program:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Include *.py | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath atom.exe -ArgumentList "`"$($_.FullName)`""}
```

Adjust the path to your external program if needed and also the the argument list (named arguments instead positional for example). Through the special quoting, this statement is prepared to even handle filenames with spaces.

If this line is to long for your *nix background, you can shrink it to:

```
gci *.py|%{start atom "`"$($_.FullName)`""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
& "Full path of atom.exe" @("*.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

If atom is set as the default for items with the .py extension you could run `gi *.py`.  Assuming this is not the case i'd right some function as part of a profile script to do this:

```
$AtomPath = "Path\To\Atom.exe"

function openWithAtom{

Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Include $args[0] | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath $AtomPath -ArgumentList "`"$($_.FullName)`""}

}

new-item alias:atom -value openWithAtom
```

then you would run it with this: `atom *.py`, or `atom filename.py`

This tutorial should help with seting up a profile https://www.howtogeek.com/126469/how-to-create-a-powershell-profile/

Also if you haven't already id style your window so it looks more like a terminal.